# Monitoring a shared folder with multiple servers

Tags: .net, windows, service, concurrency, filesystems

I've got a windows service that monitors a shared folder and when a file is created, processes it and then deletes it. For that purpose I've set a timer to query the folder for files every 10 seconds, and a BlockingCollection to split the work between multiple threads.

This solution worked fine for me so far, but now I want to run multiple instances of the service on multiple servers, monitoring the same input folder.

The problem is ofcourse synchronizing the services to not interfere with each other.

One solution that has come to mind is seperating the monitoring itself to a different 'master' node and using multiple instances as slaves, but I want the service instances to remain independant.

Any ideas from someone who has faced a similiar situation?

Answer (score 0):

If the file (let's name it "filename.ext") can be opened in exclusive mode for processing, that would be great for you as you won't need to do anything other than open that file.

If the folder itself is writable, you can create a semaphore file named "filename.ext.sem" there to let other services know that the "filename.ext" file is being processed.

If none of the above works for you, then you need some centralized place to serve as a placeholder for semaphores (be it files, DB records or something else).

In more complicated you would need to build a scheme with dynamic master, where one of instances plays the role of the master and others are slave, but that would be an overkill in your case.